# Starting the Synergys server on mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking

Here is the line I'm having trouble with...

"Drag the synergys program from the synergy folder onto the Terminal window."

I'm assuming this means a specific file within the synergy-1.3.1 folder, but I don't know which one... (unless I'm suppose to compile this first and then have a build file that I'm suppose to drag to the terminal and run the command on?)

The configuration seems pretty easy providing I get the hostname correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`synergys` is the name of the synergy server binary (`synergyc` is the client). If you downloaded source code then naturally you'll need to compile it first, but synergy also comes as a [pre-built package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy2/files/)

Comment: I downloaded the pre-build zip, but not sure that's actually what I wanted. This URL shows the various files...
http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergy2/files/
... looks like I needed the OS X tar.

Think I can get it now.